# How to use variables output by webpack?

Tags: javascript, git, reactjs, webpack

I am trying to display git commit hash in my react application using https://www.npmjs.com/package/git-revision-webpack-plugin this webpack plugin that supposedly exposes `COMMITHASH` variable

In my jsx I included:

`<p>{process.COMMITHASH}</p>`

and installed plugin in production webpack config as described:

```
plugins: [
  new GitRevisionPlugin()
]
```

yet generated html returns `<p></p>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to access the `COMMITHASH` variable inside your code, you need to use the `Define` plugin, just as it says in the documentation here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/git-revision-webpack-plugin#plugin-api

```
var GitRevisionPlugin = require('git-revision-webpack-plugin');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var gitRevisionPlugin = new GitRevisionPlugin()

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'VERSION': JSON.stringify(gitRevisionPlugin.version()),
      'COMMITHASH': JSON.stringify(gitRevisionPlugin.commithash()),
    })
  ]
};
```

Then every occurrence of `COMMITHASH` "constant" in your code should be replaced by webpack when you build the bundle.